# UNION All, Group BY and then get overall COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, union

I have 2 Tables..

**User 1**

```
user_id     mobile_no
   1          1111
   2          2222
```

**User 2**

```
user_id     mobile_no
   1          3333
   2          2222
```

I Want to first UNION These tables, then group by and then want to count total records

I am using this query but it's not working

```
SELECT COUNT(Q2.total) AS Overall
FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(Q.user_id) AS total
   FROM (
     SELECT * FROM user1
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT * FROM user2
   ) Q
  GROUP BY Q.mobile_no
) Q2
```

if i user Inner Query e-g:

```
   SELECT COUNT(Q.user_id) AS total
   FROM (
     SELECT * FROM user1
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT * FROM user2
   ) Q
  GROUP BY Q.mobile_no
```

I get these results, actually i want to again count these result...

```
total
 2
 1
 1
```

i expect this result

```
Overall
   3
```

Comment: What is the result supposed to show? Are you looking for the distinct number of values in `mobile_no`?

Comment: i have edited my question now can you please find any solution for me..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is weird. No one seems to have realised it's as simple as:

```
select count(*) overall
from (select mobile_no from user1 union select mobile_no from user2)
```

The difference between `union` and `union all` is that `union` removes duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count (distinct mobile_no) from
(select user_id, mobile_no from user1 u1
UNION ALL
select user_id, mobile_no from user2 u2
) X
group by X.mobile_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather use [UNION and not UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

[SQL UNION Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

> The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow
>   duplicate values, use the ALL keyword with UNION.

```
SELECT  COUNT(mobile_no) Overall
FROM    (
            SELECT  
                    mobile_no
            FROM    User1
            UNION
            SELECT  
                    mobile_no
            FROM    User2
        ) Q
```

**EDIT:**

As @Bohemian correctly stated, no need for the distinct.

Comment: dont need distinct with union: union only returns distinct values overall. if you removed those two distinct keywords nothing will change.

Comment: @Bohemian, but what if there are duplicates in the same table?

Comment: union (not union all) returns only distinct values from the union, so it does't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are looking for the distinct number of mobile numbers:

```
select count(distinct mobile_no) as Overall
from (
  select user_id, mobile_no
  from user1
  union all
  select user_id, mobile_no
  from user2
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
   ( (SELECT * FROM user1) UNION 
      (SELECT user_id as u1,mobile_no as m1
      FROM user2) )  as a1  GROUP BY a1 .1
```